# How To Properly Handle Passwords In C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, security, memory

It's a well known fact that C# `string` is pretty insecure, it's not pinned in RAM, the Garbage Collector can move it, copy it, leave multiple traces of it in RAM and the RAM can be swapped and be available as a file to be read, not mentioning several other known facts.

In order to mitigate this Microsoft came up with `SecureString`. The thing is: **what is the proper way of using it?**

I ask this because sooner or later you will have to extract the inner string. And yes, `SecureString` does allow us to write one `char` at a time and gives us some other minor usages while hiding it's secret, but sometimes we need the whole string at once or something like it. So far all implementations I see use a regular `string` at the end, with the extracted and decrypted content from the `SecureString` which I think (or hope) it's avoidable in some cases even though it might involve some complicated code to get around a .NET `string`.

In my case I use a library for password hashing called [BCrypt](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/). It uses a regular `string` for calculating the hashes, which I think is far from ideal. I didn't find any libraries that would accept a `SecureString` directly, so I don't have much of an option but use it.

Currently I run code such as this:

```
SecureString password; // This usually comes from a PasswordBox Property
IntPtr passwordBSTR = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(password);

string insecurePassword = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(passwordBSTR);
Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(passwordBSTR);
passwordBSTR = default(IntPtr);
password.Clear();

// Use the insecurePassword....usually as:
bool result = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(insecurePassword, user.Password); // This hashes the provided password and compares it with another BCrypt hash.

insecureString = string.Empty; // hoping for the GC to act now, fingers crossed.

// use result and etc...
```

This way the password raw `string` will be copied multiple times for the `BCrypt` method and probably even more times inside it.

This makes some questions arise in my mind:

1 - **Are `BSTR` strings like `C` strings in the sense of memory management?** Are they pinned in RAM and I can manipulate them and erase them as I see fit so it will be more secure to use them in C# or interop it with a C++ code so I can eliminate a lot of my .NET `string` manipulations (like verifying if the password string is null or white space or has the correct length or has the desired password strength)?

2 - If question's #1 answer is "yes" then **should I invest some time to pass the BSTR string to a interop C++ code to calculate it's hash and verify?**

3 - Is my later code correct or am I missing something on `SecureString` manipulation?

**Just to be clear:** My main intent with this question is to evaluate if I should pass all my password handling code to C++ from my C# (probably using C++/CLI or interop) to achieve a more secure code than what C# has to offer. This scenario really concerns me for password string hashing were multiple strings will be created and copied with the user's secret information scattered all over the RAM.

As an example: I could make a method like:

```
public string SecureHash(SecureString password)
```

And this method will extract the `SecureString` value and pass it as a `BSTR` string (or other extraction option, I honestly don't know the benefits between them) to a C++ hashing method, so we can control all the places our password sits in memory.

**I ask this to not have a huge work refactoring my code and in the end discover it was all for nothing because I was using `SecureStrings` wrongly all the time and there are already solutions for this, or a false sense of security, as it happens sometimes, since I am not aware of how `BSTR` strings are implemented in memory or the other `SecureStrings` [extraction options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx#interop) (Unicode, ANSI and etc).**

Comment: you could re-write BCrypt to have a method that takes a secure string instead. According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx#HowSecure is not actually that secure if you have to modify the string frequently etc.

Comment: @MattClark That's exactly my idea. My question is to either it's worth it or not. I am not aware of the memory behavior of BSTR strings so I might have all the trouble for a false sense of security.

Comment: BSTR doesn't actually gain you anything over SecureString, especially because BSTR is jsut an unencrypted string in unmanaged memory. In the case of both secure string and bstr you can manually garbage collect them.

Comment: I don't intend to gain anything from SecureString over BSTR. The idea is to pass a SecureString to a method that will hash it's secret value. Inside the method there will be just BSTR manipulation, since the SecureString value will be extracted to a BSTR. But I am not sure how will this be more secure than a simple string, since I am not aware of the BSTR behavior in memory and even if BSTR is the best option, since there are other options to decrypt like `CoTaskMemAnsi`, `CoTaskMemUnicode`, `GlobalAllocAnsi` and `GlobalAllocUnicode`.

Comment: SecureString is just "more secure" than .NET string. But sure, using this implementation of BCrypt completely defeats the purpose of SecureString. Using SecureString should be a pretty viral process, you should *never* use a .NET string that copies it in or out. You should always rely on non-.NET string (such as BSTR which is equivalent to C/C++ string, allocated on the COM heap) for the reasons described in the SecureString msdn article (single instance, deterministic deallocation, no additional copies, etc.).

Comment: @SimonMourier yep, that's my understanding. So do you think it's worth to hash it in C++? Do you know any C# libraries that will do it automatically and are reliable?

Comment: If you're running on Windows, I would simply interop with native Windows API like the BCryptHashData function, for example (a bit hacky): http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93111/hashing-a-securestring-using-cryptography-next-generation

Answer (score 2):

1. Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR() will create a BSTR string (i.e. an array of bytes) in unmanaged memory and return a pointer to it; it means the underlying value is pinned. The value itself is a sequence of Unicode characters representing your string, prefixed with string length, and followed by two subsequent null characters (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx).
   On the other hand, Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR() will return a .Net System.String object, which is insecure.
2. I would say your options are:

   - Convert your SecureString object to unmanaged object and then pass to any 
     unmanaged library which calculates hashes
   - Use SecureString everywhere in your stack, in your case it means to rewrite BCrypt.Net to work with SecureString objects (the library is open source and really small: https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BCrypt.Net/BCrypt.cs), or find an alternative managed implementation. But since SecureString doesn't provide methods to read its data, you will need to convert it to, most likely unmanaged, string anyway at some point (you can use that unmanaged data from your managed code though).
3. You're missing correct disposal of SecureString (either within "using" or try/finally).

Comment: 1- Should it make a difference in the hash if I convert it to BSTR or Unicode? Marshal has some options of conversion and I am not sure what's the best one. 2- I don't think it's possible to be safe with a managed implementation, one way or the other I will have to extract the contents of the SecureString in C# and this might lead to other problems made by managed code, I am still thinking using an unmanaged code or library is the best, and probably joining both implementations, a managed library that takes a SecureString and processes it internally as unmanaged code and returns a .NET string

Comment: 3- Yes, I didn't mention it because this part is pretty well documented. I am using the Clear() method, onde I am finished with it, since I am getting it from a PasswordBox.

Comment: #1: If your algorithm calculates hash from your pwd as a sequence of _characters_, there should be no difference what representation (BSTR, UTF-8, etc.) you are using. On the other hand, if you calculate hash from your pwd's byte _representation_, there will be a difference. I wouldn't do the latter though, because you may introduce subtle bugs (say, your passwords are currently in BSTR, you calculated hashes and stored them in your database, then 2 years later your front-end changes and you started receiving pwds in UTF-8, which results in different hashes and nobody can log in anymore).

Comment: #2. You are right, I was mistaken about SecureString API. I was under impression you can read it character by character. I updated the answer.

Comment: #1: So when I convert a .NET String to BSTR or all the others, their bytes are all going to be the same? Just the termination ('\0''\0')will change?

Comment: Let me rephrase my answer. The _bytes_ returned by SecureStringToAnsi/SecureStringToBSTR/etc. will be (or may be) different. So it makes sense to encapsulate a conversion from SecureString to IntPtr in your "password hashing" library and never update it (or consider such an update as a breaking change in the library).

Comment: Or let the user choose the proper inner behavior which is probably how I am going to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method to the SecureString:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class SecureStringExtensions 
{
    public static T Decrypt<T>(this SecureString ss, Func<string, T> handler) 
    {
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));
        }

        var ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(ss);
        try {
            return handler(Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr));
        } finally {
            Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the decrypted string stays on the stack and will get quickly overwritten by future stack variables.

Comment: That's not the issue... The issue is that all the bcrypt frameworks for C# use unsecure strings... Your code is just a encapsulated way to extract the BSTR string from a SecureString for a Function that can already process a BSTR string... Just a helper method but that doesn't hash any password strings or do anything special as asked... I can't get a bcrypt hash using this, I can't get anything but the underling BSTR string, which isn't what the question is all about.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a one way crypt (HASH)?  Save the random salt with the crypted password and push those 2 value around.  That way you can crypt the password you want to check with the same salt and compare the encrypted values.  I would recommend SHA-256 or stronger.

As for security, this is pretty much the same method Microsoft uses in C# AspNet Membership.  Since this is pretty much industry standard with Dot Net, this level of security should work for you as well.

Here is a good source to look at how to do that:
http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx

Comment: You are providing a code form 2002. In 2016 things have changed completely. BCrypt is the current standard for password hash storage (PBKDF2 the second closest best option and scrypt a good solution too, just too new to be trusted by most). SHA256 is too fast, you can find a match using dictionary attacks running on GPUs these days. For reference: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/rainbow-table-is-dead.html